# How to get list of staged files for commit ? (fullpaths)

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I'm trying to get the list of files staged for the next commit. I want their fullpath based on the repository's base directory.

How do I do that in python, with or even better, without the gitpython module ?

I have a starter :

```
repo = git.Repo()
staged_files = repo.index.diff("HEAD")
```

but I can't access their path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found 2 ways of doing it :

**Using gitpython :**

```
repo = git.Repo()
staged_files = repo.index.diff("HEAD")
for x in staged_files:
    print(x.a_path) # Here we can use a_path or b_path, I do not know the difference...
```

**Without gitpython :**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.getoutput(['git diff --name-only --cached'])
```

And **even better** :

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'diff', '--name-only', '--cached'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
staged_files = proc.stdout.readlines()
staged_files = [f.decode('utf-8') for f in staged_files]
staged_files = [f.strip() for f in staged_files]
print(staged_files)
```